# How to pass the argument to the promise function in the JavaScript for-each cycle

Tags: javascript

I have the list of document elements. I want to change elements’ outerHtml with html. HTML is loaded from files in cycle, so I use promises. The problem is with passing the element to promise function in the cycle, because only the last element from array is passed.

```
 ...
 /**
 * Set outer html of element.
 * @param element
 * @param newHtml
 */
setOuterHtml = function(element, newHtml){    
    console.log("ELEMENT ", element); // always <ge-test-2></ge-test-2>
    element.outerHTML = newHtml;
}

this.loadElementsToHtml = function(){
    console.log(this.elements); 
    //[ge-survey, ge-test-1, ge-test-2]
    var promises  = [];
    for(var i=0; i<this.elements.length; i++){
        var el = this.elements[i];
        // laod html from file
        var elPromise = this.loadHtml(el);
        // set outer html when HTML is loaded
        //// problem here with el !!! always ge-test-2 element
        elPromise.then(res => setOuterHtml(el,res)); 
        promises.push(elPromise);
    }

    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem here is that the `el` variable is changing as you loop through the elements, and when the loop is done, `el` will refer to the last element in the array.

A simple (and cleaner) way to do this correctly is to use `.map()` so that each iteration gets its own scope:

```
this.loadElementsToHtml = function(){
    console.log(this.elements); 
    //[ge-survey, ge-test-1, ge-test-2]

    return Promise.all(this.elements.map(el => 
        this.loadHtml(el).then(res => setOuterHtml(el, res));
    ));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You seem to already have the element inside `this.elements`, just pass that one on with its index.

```
this.loadElementsToHtml = function(){
    console.log(this.elements); 
    var promises  = [];
    for(var i=0; i<this.elements.length; i++){
        // laod html from file
        var elPromise = this.loadHtml(this.elements[i]);
        elPromise.then(res => setOuterHtml(this.elements[i], res)); 
        promises.push(elPromise);
    }

    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: Same problem: There's only one `i` variable shared by all closures.